# Windows 10 Taskbar program flashing but not opening when called

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

When I right click a local file and choose "Edit with (...)" while the program running, the program starts to flash in the taskbar, but it doesn't open on the screen unless I click on it.  How can I make that program open normally on the screen?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Could you please provide pictures?

Comment: That is normal Windows 10 behaviour. Either have the program closed normally, or just accept the normal behaviour.

Comment: @Virtuality https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI8Dx.jpg

Comment: @John Can't it be fixed for a particular program using regedit or something?

Comment: Feature changes may change Regedit changes so I do not do that

Comment: Documents you open with that applications are "stacked" in the Task Bar, so that you can right-click on the icon and choose which one you want to switch to. On the other hand, Alt-Tab should provide you with a way to display the document you've just opened as first choice, since it's in the last active window.

Comment: @Didier It doesn't get stacked in the Alt+Tab icons as the last active window.

Comment: Then there must be an option or preference that lets you do what you want, like bring the main window in focus when opening a new document. You don't happen to have enabled Focus Assist, by chance?

Comment: @Didier Focus Assistant is off.

Comment: @Virtuality There was no answer to my question, I am already calling the file to be opened with that program.  It just flashes without opening. So the answer wasn't what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

When a taskbar icon flashes orange, it is flashing orange because the application is telling WIndows it wants/requires the user's attention. There is no way to get the flashing application to restore the window/open on the screen automatically. If Windows could do this, there would be no need for the icon to flash orange, Windows could just open it on the screen anyway. **You** need to manually click on the icon to see why it wants your attention.

Maybe this could be achieved by a third-party application, but I do not currently know of one.